# OpenERP reports - What are the OpenOffice Writer properties for?

Tags: reporting, odoo, rml

I have been searching the web, this site and obviously the developers section on reports from OpenERP and I can not find any explanation as what the Openwriter properties/User defined are used for.

Spending some time on developing a first report, I came to some conclusion but can't work it all out:
There are three columns: Name, Type and Value. In all the predefined OpenERP reports I have opened using Openwriter, the schema seems to be always the same. Four rows, "Info 1" to "Info 4", all with the type "text", and then the server location, the user login id, a number and a table name.

I understand that the server location and user login id will be used when connecting to the server. 
I understand that the table name will be used when creating a loop object.

- **Question 1:** But what is the number for, the one usually corresponding to Info 3? I thought it might be the res_model id from the ir_act_window table but I found a report that doesn't match (Crossovered analytic). Any idea what the number is for and how it is defined?

**EDIT Answer 1:** It is linked to the binding action. When creating a new report for an existing model, then an existing binding action value on this model should be incremented by one (well, that's the theory as I haven't tried yet).

- **Question 2:** Why is the type "text" when Info 3 is a number? I guess it is the interpretation from python and that it is the way it is and this is the only way to configure the properties to operate with OpenERP. Can someone confirm?
- **Question 3:** Why when I add Info 5 and Info 6, pointing out to another table, hoping to create a loop on a different table, it gets totally ignored?
- **Question 4:** Why when binding to the server it doesn't ask me anything and doesn't add the report anywhere?

**EDIT Answer 4:** See Answer 1 as when changing the binding action index in "Info 3" to an existing binding action index in OpenERP then it pops the binding window up.
Thanks for reading this far! I am sure answers to these questions will help a lot of people understanding at least the basic connection between Openwriter and OpenERP.

EDIT: Thanks Amit for the formatting, it is much more readable this way and I will apply it to my next messages.

Comment: Open Office Writer, the reporting development tool for OpenERP.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Openwriter is - I suggest you try a different reporting engine. The easiest imo is the webkit html reports, you can use normal html and "mako" templating code to iterate through the objects.

Comment: Sorry for taking a deceiving shortcut, I meant OpenOffice Writer.

Comment: Ah, I thought it might be. I dont like the OpenOffice reports.. Pain to use. I would seriously try out a different report engine. Is this for your own module or are you trying to change someone else's report?

Comment: I created a new sale_order.rml report, totally different from the built in one.  I also find OpenOffice writer painful to use and I now have to modify the rml file itself as OpenOffice writer is not precise enough. But it's got some good options as well. I need to try another rml report tool.